# jquery filter xml data by attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

xml code:

```
<area>
 <point area="54" lat="44.744081" lng="-62.790818" />
 <point area="54" lat="44.743851" lng="-62.792953" />
 <point area="54" lat="44.744439" lng="-62.794366" />
 <point area="55" lat="44.786528" lng="-62.835136" />
 <point area="55" lat="44.787447" lng="-62.835955" />
 <point area="55" lat="44.786528" lng="-62.835136" />
 <point area="56" lat="44.746209" lng="-62.83688" />
 <point area="56" lat="44.745966" lng="-62.836843" />
 <point area="56" lat="44.746246" lng="-62.836481" />
 <point area="56" lat="44.746209" lng="-62.83688" />
</area>
```

I would like to retrieve filtered information by the area number.  in my jQuery code, I have:

```
$(xml).find('point').each(function(){
  var area = $(this).attr('area');
  if(area == 56){
    var alat=$(this).attr('lat');
    var alng=$(this).attr('lng');
    string += 'lat= ' + alat + ', lng=' + alng;
    }       
  });
```

I saw some suggestions online and thought I could do it this way:

```
$(xml).find("point[area='56']").each(function(){
    var alat=$(this).attr('lat');
    var alng=$(this).attr('lng');
    string += 'lat= ' + alat + ', lng=' + alng;      
  });
```

So how I can streamline my code well so I can use loop through xml files to get each area for different arrangements?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean when you say "for different arragements". Can you elaborate?

Comment: What exactly do you want help with?

Comment: I acctually like to draw polygons on google V3 and each area is the coordinates of this polygon.  So when people click on area 56, jquery will get coordinates from xml and show this polygon on the map only.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a selector like this:

```
$(xml).find("[area][area!=]")
```

which will find all elements in the xml text that have an `area` attribute that isn't empty